# Change mouse button behavior

Tags: mouse, button, xbindkeys

I have been playing around with xbindkeys and somehow managed to make the primary button copy and middle button paste. When I highlight text, it is added to my clipboard.

This behavior doesn't appeal to me and I would want my buttons to be normal again.

`$HOME/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
# For the benefit of emacs users: -*- shell-script -*-
###########################
# xbindkeys configuration #
###########################
#
# Version: 1.8.7
#
# If you edit this file, do not forget to uncomment any lines
# that you change.
# The pound(#) symbol may be used anywhere for comments.
#
# To specify a key, you can use 'xbindkeys --key' or
# 'xbindkeys --multikey' and put one of the two lines in this file.
#
# The format of a command line is:
#    "command to start"
#       associated key
#
#
# A list of keys is in /usr/include/X11/keysym.h and in
# /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
# The XK_ is not needed.
#
# List of modifier:
#   Release, Control, Shift, Mod1 (Alt), Mod2 (NumLock),
#   Mod3 (CapsLock), Mod4, Mod5 (Scroll).
#

# The release modifier is not a standard X modifier, but you can
# use it if you want to catch release events instead of press events

# By defaults, xbindkeys does not pay attention with the modifiers
# NumLock, CapsLock and ScrollLock.
# Uncomment the lines above if you want to pay attention to them.

#keystate_numlock = enable
#keystate_capslock = enable
#keystate_scrolllock= enable

# Examples of commands:

"xbindkeys_show" 
  control+shift + q

# set directly keycode (here control + f with my keyboard)
#"xterm"
#  c:41 + m:0x4

# specify a mouse button
#"xterm"
#  control + b:2

#"xterm -geom 50x20+20+20"
#   Shift+Mod2+alt + s
#
## set directly keycode (here control+alt+mod2 + f with my keyboard)
#"xterm"
#  alt + c:0x29 + m:4 + mod2
#
## Control+Shift+a  release event starts rxvt
#"rxvt"
#  release+control+shift + a
#
## Control + mouse button 2 release event starts rxvt
#"rxvt"
#  Control + b:2 + Release

# Back changed to Copy
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key C' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:9
# Front changed to Paste
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key V' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:8
##################################
# End of xbindkeys configuration #
##################################
```

`xev` output when the primary button is pressed:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x582, subw 0x5200002, time 8362463, (36,45), root:(1736,214),
    state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES
--

ButtonRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x582, subw 0x5200002, time 8362545, (36,45), root:(1736,214),
    state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
```

`xev` output for middle button:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0x582, subw 0x0, time 9840391, (63,69), root:(1763,238),
    state 0x10, button 2, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0x582, subw 0x0, time 9840487, (63,69), root:(1763,238),
    state 0x210, button 2, same_screen YES
```